# Laravel 5.1 - Facebook Authentication through Socialite

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am trying to implement Facebook Login to my project however I receive an error:

> ClientException in Middleware.php line 69:
>   Client error: 400
>
> 1. *in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laratest/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php line 69*
> 2. *at Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(object(Response)) in Promise.php line 199*
> 3. *at Promise::callHandler('1', object(Response), array(object(Promise), object(Closure), null)) in Promise.php line 152*
> 4. *at Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() in TaskQueue.php line 60*
> 5. *at TaskQueue->run() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 96*

---

Steps I've gone through:

- `composer require laravel/socialite` & `composer update`.
- In my *config>services.app*,

`'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FB_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FB_SECRET_ID'),
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost.com:8888',
],`

- Added 
  `Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,` & `'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,` in *config>app.php*
- Set up the routes successfully.

`Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');`

- Setup the link successfully in my blade file. `Login with Facebook`
- In my *Controller>AuthController.php*, I added:

  ```
  use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

  ** Beside everything that AuthController has, inside the AuthController class, I added:**

    public function redirectToProvider()
     {
      return Socialite::driver('facebook')
           ->scopes(['scope1', 'scope2'])->redirect();
     }

  /**
   * Obtain the user information from Facebook.
   *
   * @return Response
   */

     public function handleProviderCallback()
      {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

      // $user->token;
      }
  ```
- Also users table:

  ```
     public function up()
      {
         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('avatar');
            $table->string('provider');
            $table->string('provider_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
              });
      }
  ```

**Edit:**
When I comment out `$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();` part, I get redirected to `localhost.com/auth/facebook`

**Edit 2:**
My `.env` file:

`'facebook' => [
        FB_CLIENT_ID => '###',
        FB_SECRET_ID => 'this-is-secret!',
],`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your two routes should not have the same URL, because Laravel has no way to know which to use.

Facebook returns a ?code parameter, so make use of it! If ?code is included, then handle the login logic from Socialite, if not, redirect to Facebook.

**You have two unknown scopes in your code, scope1 and scope2, those are unknown to Facebook and will return an error when trying to access them. Use real scopes like public_profile or email and you should be set. (scopes are the permissions you are requesting)**

Comment: Good call, the two identical GET routes are indeed likely to be a problem.

Comment: ->scopes(['scope1', 'scope2']) might also cause issues, are they really like that in your controller? If so, those are unknown to Facebook and it will likely deny the request.

Comment: I added `auth/facebook/callback` for the second Route, and now it is directing to Facebook. However, as @Francismori7 said, here there is an error I receive: Facebook error -> `Invalid Scope: scope1`. Should I just delete the `->scopes(['scope1', 'scope2'])->redirect();` part completely?

Comment: @senty, you should include the scopes that you require! Example public_profile and email

Comment: @Francismori7, I left it as  `return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();` and now it is directing to FB successfully, however I face with an error now: `Invalid App ID -> #MyAppid#` while I have oauth client on the link bar... `fb.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=>+bla bla bla bla bla`

Comment: @Francismori7 *EDIT*: I now added `->scopes(['public_profile', 'email'])->redirect();` but I am still running into the error Invalid App ID (but it's not). I even turned the app ON on facebook.

Comment: .env files should look like

FB_CLIENT_ID=YOURCLIENTIDHERE
FB_SECRET_ID=SECRETCODEHERE

Keep in mind that .env files are NOT PHP files, they ressemble INI config files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84019/discussion-between-francismori7-and-senty).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Laravel is calling properly your config entries with

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And also check your .env file for FB_CLIENT_ID and FB_SECRET_ID entries. Probably client's failing because it's trying to connect to facebook without client and secret, falling into an exception.

Comment: I have just edited the OP, showing my .env file. I have tried `config:clear` but still no luck. I also activated the Facebook app to public (became green circle) but still the same error

Comment: Don't post your .env file here! Anyone can see it and could be used by any of us...

Comment: I felt exhausted. Been working on this problem for almost a day trying to figure out what's wrong. Do you have any clue?

Comment: In your facebook app settings page, is your Site Url properly configured with localhost?

Comment: I have configured and using http://laratest.dev/ as localhost/project to access the page. Both redirect_url in laravel and facebook>settings>basic> site URL: http://laratest.dev/ and App Domains: 'laravel.dev'. Is it where I am missing out smt?

Comment: When you access the site, you're doing it through laratest.dev or localhost/project?

Comment: I am going through laratest.dev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83930/discussion-between-senty-and-rotvulpix).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem(ClientException in Middleware.php line 69: Client error: 400). 
I just switch off "Require App Secret " in the facebook's advanced settings and this solved the problem. Maybe this information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Facebook APi - it gave Response code 400
and Ive just tried:

**composer require laravel/socialite & composer update**

and it updated dependencis:

**Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/socialite (v2.0.11)
  - Installing laravel/socialite (v2.0.14)**

Im Using Laravel 5.1:

composer.json:

```
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0"
```

And it seems to work fine now

Hope this helps someone